# According to Catholicism, why are some demons more difficult to cast out than others?

Tags: catholicism, demons, gospel-of-mark, exorcism

In the gospels we often read about Jesus casting out demons. But there is one episode, where the disciples were unable to cast out a demon (Mark 9: 27-28).

> 27 And when he was come into the house, his disciples secretly asked him: Why could not we cast him out?
>
> 28 And he said to them: This kind can go out by nothing, but by prayer and fasting.

Some time ago, I was reading [an article](http://www.beliefnet.com/Faiths/2000/09/Pope-Performs-Exorcism-Over-Teenage-Italian-Girl.aspx) stating that Pope John Paul II was unable to liberate an Italian teenager from a demon during an exorcism!

My question is this: according to Catholic teaching, why are some demons harder to cast out than others?

Comment: [Did you read about this in the Guardian?](http://www.theguardian.com/world/1999/jan/27/religion.uk)  From your linked question, it appears that part of the answer is further down in the article.  Start from where it says  "Not even your [church] head can send me away."

Comment: Like many things, it is likely that the Catholic Church has not declared a specific reason for why that might be, only that it is the case that it is that way.

Comment: The manual that they recently updated is only issued in Latin as far I know, so I can't be of any help.  *De Exorcismis et supplicationibus quibusdam*.  Not sure where you can get a copy, if interested.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there are different levels or hierarchies of angels, demons being fallen angels. If one gets possessed/oppressed by a more malignant demon, its exorcism would be more difficult because such a demon is more disobedient to God.

Listen to [the talks **here**](https://sentrad.org/multimedia/) by a Catholic priest who is an expert in demonology and exorcism, e.g. the

- ones listed under the heading "**Angels and Demons**"
- "TU Newman Center Conference on Exorcism" talk
- "Interview on Exorcism, Reason in Society, Philosophy and Theology"